# databricks error importing using cloudfiles

Tags: sql, databricks, delta-live-tables

I am trying to import data using cloudfiles in databricks. 2 different ways give me errors. With

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE orders_raw
COMMENT "The raw books orders, ingested from orders-raw"
AS SELECT * FROM cloud_files("${datasets_path}/orders-raw", "parquet",
                             map("schema", "order_id STRING, order_timestamp LONG customer_id STRING, quantity LONG")
                             )
```

I get:

```
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'STRING'.(line 1, pos 9)

== SQL ==
order_id STRING, order_timestamp LONG customer_id STRING, quantity LONG
---------^^^
```

And with :

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE orders_raw
COMMENT "The raw books orders, ingested from orders-raw"
AS SELECT * FROM cloud_files("${datasets_path}/orders-json-raw", "json",
                             map("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true")
                             )
```

The error is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> cloudFiles.schemaLocation Could not find required option:
> schemaLocation. Please provide a schema location using
> `cloudFiles.schemaLocation` for storing inferred schema and supporting
> schema evolution.

any help? thanks

Comment: the first method is solved, was missing a comma. still interested in why the second is not working with `schemaLocation` error

Comment: Is it Databricks SQL or Delta Live Tables?

Comment: it is DLT you're right

Comment: Hmmm, interesting - DLT should handle schema evolution automatically: https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/dlt.html